# Wordpress: Use Pagination with showing child pages

Tags: wordpress, pagination, parent-child

Below is the code I'm currently using to display the child pages on my parent page. This code is working just fine however it's querying all 240+ child pages on one page. I would like to limit this to 20 per page and add pagination like with posts. Is this possible? Also note I'm using 'number' => 62 which for some reason queries back to 15 on the page. I can live with this.

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'asc' , 'number' => 62 ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
        $content = $page->post_content;
        if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
            continue;

        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

I then call the page thumbnail, page title, and 2 post_meta (Custom field) queries.

```
php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail');

php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title;

$key="Type"; echo get_post_meta($page->ID, $key, true);

echo get_the_term_list( $page->ID, 'areas', '', ', ', '' );
```

Can I use something like this before $mypages = get_pages?

```
$page_num = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
```

in my query to get pages to show a paged view. The final query looked like this. Hopefully this helps someone.

```
$args = array(

        'meta_key' => 'surname',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '20',
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
);  

query_posts( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```